# For Loop Gives #VALUE error When Run Uninterrupted, But Works With Debugger In VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, valueerror

I've created a custom function I'm using in a worksheet that uses a cell reference I pass into it to gather date data from 2 worksheets in the same workbook, then calculates a value using these dates. It was working just fine yesterday, then when I made a change to the cell that's passed as the reference(all I did was change how the cell value was retrieved in the formula bar from a relative path to just the worksheet name) I started getting a #VALUE error. The weird thing is that my code seems to be correct, and when I put a break point just at the part where I change the variables from String variables to Date variables, and I walk through it, it always works, but when I try to run it uninterrupted, I keep getting the #VALUE error. This is my full custom function:

```
Function difference_in_days(device_ID_ref As Range) As Variant
Dim searchRange1 As Range
Dim searchRange2 As Range
Dim results As Collection
Dim result() As Variant
Dim temp() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim foundCell As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim CodesUsedSheet As Worksheet
Dim InputInAppSheet As Worksheet

' Setup the worksheets and ranges
Set CodesUsedSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Codes Used")
Set InputInAppSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input in-app")

Set searchRange1 = CodesUsedSheet.UsedRange
Set searchRange2 = InputInAppSheet.UsedRange
Set results = New Collection

 ' Search in the Codes Used worksheet
Set foundCell = searchRange1.Find(What:=device_ID_ref.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    Dim retrievedValue As Variant
    firstAddress = foundCell.Address
    Do
        retrievedValue = CodesUsedSheet.Range(foundCell.Address).Offset(0, 20).Value
        On Error Resume Next
        results.Add retrievedValue, CStr(retrievedValue)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set foundCell = searchRange1.Find(What:=device_ID_ref.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, after:=foundCell)
    
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> firstAddress
End If

 ' Search in the Input In-App worksheet
Set foundCell = searchRange2.Find(device_ID_ref.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = foundCell.Address
    Do
        retrievedValue = InputInAppSheet.Range(foundCell.Address).Offset(0, 11).Value
        On Error Resume Next
        results.Add retrievedValue, CStr(retrievedValue)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set foundCell = searchRange2.Find(What:=device_ID_ref.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, after:=foundCell)
    
    Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> firstAddress
End If

 ' Convert the results collection to a temp array
ReDim temp(1 To results.Count)
For i = 1 To results.Count
    temp(i) = results(i)
Next i

' Sort the array in ascending order and redimension
result = WorksheetFunction.Sort(temp, 1, 1, True)
ReDim Preserve result(LBound(result) To UBound(result))

'Change array values back to date type
Dim dateValue As Date
For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
    dateValue = CDate(result(i))
    result(i) = dateValue
    Debug.Print result(i) & " " & TypeName(result(i)) & " " & i
Next i


'Calculate the date difference
Dim difference As Long: difference = 0
For i = LBound(result) To (UBound(result) - 1)
    difference = difference + (result(i + 1) - result(i))
Next i

Dim finalResult As Double
finalResult = difference / (UBound(result) - 1)

difference_in_days = finalResult
End Function
```

I've tried adding error handling lines to my code, it never errors out, only gives an Error 0- alert, and like I said, it goes into the loop to change into Date variables, correctly works on the first element and then seems to just stop there. None of my debug statements after the loop are printed. I've also tried to change the loop being used, and that did not work as well.

Comment: If you call your function from a Sub instead of from a worksheet cell, you'll be able to debug it.